# How to split two containers in 60% / 40% and position text at the bottom of a container in Flutter?

Tags: positioning, flutter

I am trying to create something similar like the image below, where there are two containers, one that takes 40% of the screen and the other one the rest of the screen.

In the top container I would like to have a text at the top and one at the bottom, left aligned.

I have this:

```
 // main page body
 body: Container(
    child: Column(
      children: [

        // top container
        new Expanded(
          child: null, // todo, add the two texts,
        ),

        // bottom container
        new Container(
          height: 400.0,  // this needs to be 60% of the page
          child: new Text('test'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

[image]

Comment: Use Flex property

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`Expanded`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) widget with [`flex`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Flex-class.html) property.

This is how I did it:

```
//with dart 2 new and const keywords are optional
void main() => runApp(new MaterialApp(home: new HomePage(),));

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {

  final text = new Text('Text here', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 50.0),);

  final margin = const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0, right: 10.0, left: 10.0);

  final backColor = Colors.lightGreen;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width; // Using this line I got the device screen width

    return new Scaffold(
      body: new SafeArea(//I didnt add appbar. this will add necessary padding for status bar.
        child: new Column(
        children: [
          new Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: new Container(
              width: width /1.5, // this will give you flexible width not fixed width
              margin: margin, // variable
              color: backColor,// variable
              child: new Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: new Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                      child: text, //varaible above
                    ),
                  ),
                  new Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: new Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      child: text, //variable above
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          new Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: new Container(
              width: width /1.5, // this will give you flexible width not fixed width
              margin: margin, //variable
              color: backColor,//variable
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: @Patrioticcow have a look at the answer again I added the width propery and as a value I get the screen width and devide it by 1.5 you can change it as you want, that way this container width will change according to screen(in larger screens like tab)

Comment: Thanks m8 for saving my day, i used your answer to solve 1 more question will refer to this end