# How do I wrap content of PageView so that Indicators appear right below where PageView ends?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

How do I wrap content of PageView so that Indicators appear right below where PageView ends ?. Right now PageView fills entire screen and Indicators are at bottom of screen. Below is how each child in PageView is created. In each child I have a Image with default height of 200 and TextView with maxLines of 2 . Though actual height of each child in PageView is half of device screen , it fills entire screen .

```
final List<Widget> _pages = <Widget>[
new Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: <Widget>[
    new Image.network(
      'imageurl',
      height: 200.0,
      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
    ),
    new Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: new Text(
        "Order from wide range of restaurants",
        maxLines: 2,
        style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    )
  ],
),
new Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: <Widget>[
    new Image.network(
      'imageurl',
      height: 200.0,
      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
    ),
    new Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: new Text(
        "Order from wide range of restaurants",
        maxLines: 2,
        style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
new Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: <Widget>[
    new Image.network(
      'imageurl',
      height: 200.0,
      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
    ),
    new Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: new Text(
        "Order from wide range of restaurants",
        maxLines: 2,
        style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    )
  ],
)
];
```

Stateful Widget's Builder method

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  children: <Widget>[
    new Flexible(
      child: new PageView.builder(
        physics: new AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        controller: _controller,
        itemCount: _pages.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return _pages[index % _pages.length];
        },
      ),
      fit: FlexFit.loose,
    ),
    new Container(
      color: Colors.black,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: new Center(
        child: new DotsIndicator(
          controller: _controller,
          itemCount: _pages.length,
          onPageSelected: (int page) {
            _controller.animateToPage(
              page,
              duration: _kDuration,
              curve: _kCurve,
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    )
  ],
);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here my solution, as you didn't pasted entire source code, i have omitted dots section

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class PageViewIssue extends StatefulWidget {
      PageViewIssue({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

      static const String routeName = "/PageViewIssue";

      final String title;

      @override
      _PageViewIssueState createState() => new _PageViewIssueState();
    }

    class _PageViewIssueState extends State<PageViewIssue> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text(widget.title),
          ),
          body: _getBodyContent(),
          floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: _onFloatingActionButtonPressed,
            tooltip: 'Add',
            child: new Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
        );
      }

      void _onFloatingActionButtonPressed() {}

      List<Widget> _getPageViews() {
        final String imgUrl =
            "https://images.pexels.com/photos/45201/kitty-cat-kitten-pet-45201.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=320&w=320";
        final List<Widget> _pages = <Widget>[
          new Center(
              child: new Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Center(
                  child: new Image.network(
                imgUrl,
                height: 200.0,
                fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
              )),
              new Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: new Text(
                  "Order from wide range of restaurants",
                  maxLines: 2,
                  style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              )
            ],
          )),
          new Center(
              child: new Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Center(
                  child: new Image.network(
                imgUrl,
                height: 200.0,
                fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
              )),
              new Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: new Text(
                  "Order from wide range of restaurants",
                  maxLines: 2,
                  style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
          new Center(
              child: new Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Center(
                  child: new Image.network(
                imgUrl,
                height: 200.0,
                fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
              )),
              new Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: new Text(
                  "Order from wide range of restaurants",
                  maxLines: 2,
                  style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ))
        ];

        return _pages;
      }

      Widget _getBodyContent() {
    var controller = new PageController(initialPage: 0);
    var pageView = new PageView(
        children: _getPageViews(), pageSnapping: true, controller: controller);

    var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    var expansion1 = new Expanded(
        child:
            new Container(width: width, child: pageView, color: Colors.green),
        flex: 9);

    var expansion2 = new Expanded(
        child: new Container(
            width: width,
            child: new Center(child: new Text("Text 2")),
            color: Colors.redAccent),
        flex: 1);
    return new Column(children: <Widget>[expansion1, expansion2]);
  }
    }
```

What you were looking for is [Constrained Box](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ConstrainedBox-class.html).
[image]

Comment: In above code PageView height is hardcoded using 'constraints: const BoxConstraints.tightForFinite(height: 384.0)' . This doesn't wrap content . And if height is less part of PageView is hidden.

Comment: Updated my answer can you check.

Comment: Original reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49827520/how-to-split-two-containers-in-60-40-and-position-text-at-the-bottom-of-a-co